# How to convert string to Title Case?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to build a Title Case function that takes a string, and returns the string in title-case.

Basically, my idea was to manually upper case the first char of the string and do the rest by checking if there is 'space' before the character.

So far this is my effort.

```
string Title_Case(const string A) {
  char First_capital = static_cast<int>(A[0]) - 32;
  string B;
  B[0] = First_capital;

  for (int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) {
    if (A[i - 1] == ' ' && A[i] >= 'a' && A[i] <= 'z') {
      char capital = A[i] - ('a' - 'A');
      B += capital;
      continue;
    } else
      B = B + A[i];
  }

  return B;
}
```

Comment: The title of a question has to summarize the problem you have. `How are you doing?` is not such a title.

Comment: oh I meant 'toupper()' or the function which uppercase a character

Comment: You want to create your own toupper function. Are you aware that you have to implement a logic for each encoding. Or do you want a toupper function only for ASCII?

Comment: What is your question? You presented code and implied that you intend to improve it. Sounds good. A question would present a specific problem -- usually in the form of expected and actual results -- along with a [mre]. Even though you are trying to convert a string to Title Case, your minimal example might be more focused, such as how to detect a space or how to capitalize a character (tasks that possibly should be relegated to helper functions and not all lumped into `Title_Case()`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the function the string B is an empty string so there is no B[0], however you can assign a char to a string so the following should work

```cpp
string Title_Case (const string A){
        
        char First_capital = static_cast<int>(A[0]) - 32;
        string B;
        B = First_capital; 
        
        for ( int i =1; i <A.size(); i++){
                if( A[i-1] == ' ' &&  A[i] >= 'a' && A[i] <= 'z'){
                                char capital = A[i] - ( 'a' - 'A');
                                B += capital;
                                continue;
                        }
                else
                        B = B + A[i];
        }
        
        return B;
}
```

Comment: it is not printing the second word! but for the first word it works fine.

Comment: ````Enter a sentence: helllod  difhd dkfjd ````
````Title Case: Helllod````
This is my output

Comment: @MeharjeetSingh. It works ok if I just assign "helllod  difhd dkfjd" to a string and call the function on it. You need to post the full source code including how you are reading input.

Comment: This answer does not describe how you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

@QuatCoder's answer is correct. You are accessing the B[0] even though the length of the B string is zero.

But @Meharjeet Singh: Edge conditions have not been handled by your function.

Pre conditions for  the function above:

1. The first letter of the input string parameter is always a lowercase letter.
2. The first letter of the input string parameter is not a white space.

Edge conditions have been handled in the below function

```
string Title_Case(const string A) {
    
    string B = "";

    int pos = 0;
    int pre_pos = 0;

    pos = A.find(' ', pre_pos);

    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        string sub = "";

        sub = A.substr(pre_pos, (pos - pre_pos));

        if (pre_pos != pos)
        {
            sub = A.substr(pre_pos, (pos - pre_pos));
        }
        else 
        {
            sub = A.substr(pre_pos, 1);
        }
        
        sub[0] = toupper(sub[0]);
        B += sub + A[pos];

        if (pos < (A.length() - 1))
        {
            pre_pos = (pos + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            pre_pos = pos;
            break;
        }

        pos = A.find(' ', pre_pos);

    }

    string sub = A.substr(pre_pos, string::npos);
    sub[0] = toupper(sub[0]);
    B += sub;
    
    return B;
}
```